# Using AWS SSM Parameter Store for TypeORM config in NestJS

Tags: nestjs, typeorm, aws-ssm

I have a simple NestJS application running on AWS Lambda.  I am using the AWS SSM Parameter Store to keep database connection information and credentials. When I import TypeORM I use the parameters already retrieved from the store.

Right now I am just retrieving the params right in my AppModule where TypeORM is imported. I'm sure there is a better way to do this, but I'm not sure what it would be.  A custom Provider? Some kind of settings Service?  I don't think my current solution is very robust and there isn't great error handling.

The only requirement is that I am retrieving the SSM parameters at runtime and not at build or deploy time.  Any advice

This is what I am currently doing:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { ThingyModule } from 'thingy/thingy.module';
import * as awsParamStore from 'aws-param-store';

const ssmParams = awsParamStore.getParametersByPathSync('/myapp/prod', {region: (process.env['AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'] ? process.env['AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'] : 'us-east-2')}); 
const ssmMap = ssmParams.reduce(function(map, obj) {
  map[obj.Name] = obj.Value;
  return map;
}, {});

@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      type: 'postgres',
      host: ssmMap['/myapp/prod/db/host'],
      port: 5432,
      username: ssmMap['/myapp/prod/db/username'],
      password: ssmMap['/myapp/prod/db/password'],
      database: 'postgres',
      entities: [__dirname + '/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
      synchronize: true,
    }),
    ThingyModule
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

The parameters have been created previously with the AWS CLI:

```
// aws ssm put-parameter --type String --name /myapp/prod/db/username --value postgres --region us-east-2
// aws ssm put-parameter --type String --name /myapp/prod/db/password --value supRCkrit --region us-east-2
// aws ssm put-parameter --type String --name /myapp/prod/db/host --value localhost --region us-east-2
```

Comment: Hi, did you ever figure out how to get this working? I have the same problem :-) Thanks! I have asked a similar question here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55911569/nestjs-typeorm-configuration-using-aws-parameter-store

Comment: No, not really any better than above.  I cleaned it up and encapsulated it into a separate 'service', but still basically do it in the same place and in the same way.  At best I might move it to happen in the main handler function in index.ts where the Nest application is created. Then I know right up front that everything is ready.  I'd also probably cache the data as well.  But I haven't seen anyway there to 'pass' it to the module creation process in any direct way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this using async providers.

Sample from a working project:

Create async provider:

```
import * as AWS from 'aws-sdk';
import { Parameter } from 'aws-sdk/clients/ssm';

export const ssmProvider = {
  provide: 'AWS_SSM',
  useFactory: async (): Promise<Parameter[]> => {
    const ssmClient = new AWS.SSM({
      endpoint: 'endpoint',
      region: 'us-west-2',
    });
    const result = await ssmClient
      .getParametersByPath({
        Path: '/ssm/path',
        Recursive: true,
      })
      .promise();
    return result?.Parameters;
  },
};
```

We can then use this provider for injecting values.

For example injecting AWS SSM Parameters in config service:

```
export class ConfigModule {
  static register(options: ConfigModuleOptions): DynamicModule {
    return {
      global: true,
      module: ConfigModule,
      providers: [
        ssmProvider,
        {
          provide: CONFIG_OPTIONS,
          useValue: options,
        },
        ConfigService,
      ],
      exports: [ConfigService],
    };
  }
}
```

And in config service constructor:

```
constructor(
    @Inject(CONFIG_OPTIONS) options: ConfigOptions,
    @Inject('AWS_SSM') awsParameters: Parameter[],
  ) {}
```

**Edit**: NPM Package which provide a service which loads aws param store parameters at the application start up:

[param-store-service](https://www.npmjs.com/package/param-store-service)