# NestJs TypeORM configuration using AWS Parameter Store

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs, typeorm, aws-parameter-store

new to NestJS and have come across an issue. For our deployments we need to get our configuration from AWS Parameter Store (Systems Manager), including the database connection string. I have a ConfigModule and ConfigService which retrieves all the parameter store entries for my environment based on the param store path:

Here is my config service:

```
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';
import * as fs from 'fs';
import * as AWS from 'aws-sdk';

export class ConfigService {
    private readonly envConfig: { [key: string]: string };
    private awsParamStoreEntries: { [key: string]: string }[];

    constructor(awsParamStorePath: string, filePath: string) {
        this.envConfig = dotenv.parse(fs.readFileSync(filePath));

        this.loadAwsParameterStoreEntries(awsParamStorePath).then((data) => {
            this.awsParamStoreEntries = data;
        });
    }

    loadAwsParameterStoreEntries(pathPrefix: string) {
        const credentials = new AWS.SharedIniFileCredentials({ profile: 'grasshopper-parameter' });
        AWS.config.credentials = credentials;
        const ssm = new AWS.SSM({ region: 'us-west-2' });
        var params: { [key: string]: string }[] = [];

        return getParams({
            Path: '/app/v3/development/',
            Recursive: true,
            WithDecryption: true,
            MaxResults: 10,
        }).then(() => {
            return params;
        });

        function getParams(options) {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                ssm.getParametersByPath(options, processParams(options, (err, data) => {
                    if (err) {
                        return reject(err);
                    }
                    resolve(data);
                }));
            });
        }

        function processParams(options, cb) {
            return function (err, data) {
                if (err) {
                    return cb(err)
                };
                data.Parameters.forEach(element => {
                    let key = element.Name.split('/').join(':')
                    params.push({ key: key, value: element.Value });
                });
                if (data.NextToken) {
                    const nextOptions = Object.assign({}, options);
                    nextOptions.NextToken = data.NextToken;
                    return ssm.getParametersByPath(nextOptions, processParams(options, cb));
                }
                return cb(null);
            };
        }
    }

    get(key: string): string {
        return this.envConfig[key];
    }

    getParamStoreValue(key: string): string {
        return this.awsParamStoreEntries.find(element => element.key === key)['value'];
    }

    getDatabase(): string {
        return this.awsParamStoreEntries.find(element => element.key === 'ConnectionStrings:CoreDb')['value'];
    }
}
```

Here is the main app module declaration block:

```
@Module({
  imports: [ConfigModule, TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
    imports: [ConfigModule],
    useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => ({
      url: configService.getDatabase()
    }),
    inject: [ConfigService]
  }),
    CoreModule, AuthModule],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
```

As you can see I am telling TypeORM to call the getDatabase() method in the ConfigService *but* the problem is that it takes about 3-4 seconds for the parameter store entries to load so an "undefined" error occurs because "this.awsParamStoreEntries" is still undefined when TypeORM tries to load the connection string.

Have scoured the web to see if this has been done but could not find anything that uses NestJS / TypeORM / AWS Parameter Store in this way. There is an existing (unanswered) question here on StackOverflow as well.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Can you do something like this.

```
import { TypeOrmOptionsFactory, TypeOrmModuleOptions } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { ConfigService } from './config.service';
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';

@Injectable()
export class TypeOrmConfigService implements TypeOrmOptionsFactory {
    constructor(private readonly configService: ConfigService) {
    }

    async createTypeOrmOptions(): Promise<TypeOrmModuleOptions> {
        this.configService.awsParamStoreEntries = await this.configService.loadAwsParameterStoreEntries(this.configService.awsParamStorePath);

        return {
            url: this.configService.getDatabase(),
        };
    }
}
```

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule, 
    TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      useClass: TypeOrmConfigService,
    }),
    CoreModule, 
    AuthModule
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
```

```
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';
import * as fs from 'fs';
import * as AWS from 'aws-sdk';
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';

@Injectable()
export class ConfigService {
    private readonly envConfig: { [key: string]: string };
    awsParamStoreEntries: { [key: string]: string }[];
    private readonly awsParamStorePath: string;

    constructor(awsParamStorePath: string, filePath: string) {
        this.envConfig = dotenv.parse(fs.readFileSync(filePath));
        this.awsParamStorePath = awsParamStorePath;
    }

    loadAwsParameterStoreEntries(pathPrefix: string) {...
```

https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/database

Answer (score 1):

We can use async providers.

Sample from a working project for using AWS SSM param store parameters with NestJS config service:

Create async provider:

```
import * as AWS from 'aws-sdk';
import { Parameter } from 'aws-sdk/clients/ssm';

export const ssmProvider = {
  provide: 'AWS_SSM',
  useFactory: async (): Promise<Parameter[]> => {
    const ssmClient = new AWS.SSM({
      endpoint: 'endpoint',
      region: 'us-west-2',
    });
    const result = await ssmClient
      .getParametersByPath({
        Path: '/ssm/path',
        Recursive: true,
      })
      .promise();
    return result?.Parameters;
  },
};
```

We can then use this provider for injecting values.

For example injecting AWS SSM Parameters in config service:

```
export class ConfigModule {
  static register(options: ConfigModuleOptions): DynamicModule {
    return {
      global: true,
      module: ConfigModule,
      providers: [
        ssmProvider,
        {
          provide: CONFIG_OPTIONS,
          useValue: options,
        },
        ConfigService,
      ],
      exports: [ConfigService],
    };
  }
}
```

And in config service constructor:

```
constructor(
    @Inject(CONFIG_OPTIONS) options: ConfigOptions,
    @Inject('AWS_SSM') awsParameters: Parameter[],
  ) {}
```

**Edit**: NPM Package which provide a service which loads aws param store parameters at the application start up:

[param-store-service](https://www.npmjs.com/package/param-store-service)

Comment: Do you have a complete example of this code somewhere?

Comment: @Metallikanz I have edited my answer. Take a look at NPM package. You can use it as it is or checkout the GitHub codebase.